# Liferay SOAP services Java Client Validation Error

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, liferay, ws-i

I'm trying to use Lİferay SOAP services.But when I tried to get a client from wsdl,getting an errors like this :

[image]

I looked up this error on the internet and these are because of WS-I validation.So I tried disable WS-I validation but it did not worked either.

What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research,Jax-WS causes this error.Jax-WS did not validate liferay axis services.I tried it with Eclipse Luna with Apache axis and it worked!

Hope this helps.